# os.walk() not printing/accessing files

Tags: python, os.walk

I'm trying to use *os.walk* in order to access all files and all subfolders within a given folder. At first, my code looks like this:

```
for root, dirs, files in os.walk("/home/DataScience"):   
    for dirName in dirs:
          print dirName
```

However, the output of the above puts the *files* variable into a list-- I need it to iterate over each object within the list instead.

So I go ahead and put in an additional *for* loop as such:

```
for root, dirs, files in os.walk("/home/DataScience"):   
    for dirName in dirs:
        for fileName in files:
            print dirName
```

Now, however, there is no output. For some reason, it seems as if putting the additional loop makes it such that the *print* statement on the 4th line doesn't output properly.

My question then is this: why does this additional *for* loop eliminate my output?

Answer (score 4):

You need two separated loop for directories and files:

```
for parent, dirs, files in os.walk("/home/DataScience"):   
    for dirname in dirs:
        print dirname
    for filename in files:
        print filename
```

Comment: Interesting-- any reason why?

Comment: @ZR, Because `dirs` is a list of directories, `files` is a list of files.

Comment: The way in which I'm structuring the rest of the script seems to require me to iterate over the files after having iterated over one part of the dirs, hence why I was so keen on embedding one within the other.

Comment: @ZR: if `dirs` is empty, there are no elements within it, and no reason for any inner loops to be executed

Comment: But it seems as if that's never the case. I don't think there are any situations in which dirs is empty.

Comment: @ZR, `os.walk` recurses for you. and for each iteration, it yields subdirectories and files in a directory.

Answer (score 0):

If you only care about the files, not the folders in a directory, and you want to work with them (say, to open them), this is what you want to do:

```
import os
for root, subdirs, files in os.walk(directory):
    for file in files:
        print(root + os.sep + file)
        # or whatever file operation you're interested in
```

`subdirs`, or what you're calling `dirs`, is just a list of the folders in `root`.  On each step, `os.walk()` will step into the next subdirectory inside of `root`, making THAT `root`.  So, you don't need to go through the folders yourself.

Comment: You could use `os.path.join(root, file)`.

Comment: @falsetru That works just as well.  Do you know if either option has any inherent advantage? They are both readable and have the same dependencies.

Comment: According to [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.sep): ... Note that knowing this is not sufficient to be able to parse or concatenate pathnames — use os.path.split() and os.path.join() ...

Comment: @falsetru interesting, I wonder why, since they don't explain a reason.  os.sep hasn't ever caused me any trouble, though admittedly I'm not working on cross-platform applications.